# Error Packaging QGIS 2.9.0

Tags: qgis, installation, windows-8, osgeo4w, perl

I am attempting to package QGIS from source and the creatensis.pl script is exiting with the error:

> Running NSIS
>   Can't open script "Master'"
>   running nsis failed [makensis -V1 -DVERSION_NAME='Master' -DVERSION_NUMBER='2.9.
>   0' -DBINARY_REVISION=1 -DVERSION_INT='2090001' -DQGIS_BASE='QGIS Master' -DINSTA
>   LLER_NAME='QGIS-OSGeo4W-2.9.0-1-Setup-x86_64.exe' -DDISPLAYED_NAME='QGIS 'Master
>   ' (2.9.0)' -DSHORTNAME='qgis' -DINSTALLER_TYPE=OSGeo4W -DPACKAGE_FOLDER=osgeo4w/
>   unpacked-x86_64 -DLICENSE_FILE='osgeo4w/unpacked-x86_64/apps/qgis/doc/LICENSE' -
>   DARCH='x86_64' QGIS-Installer.nsi] at creatensis.pl line 431

UPDATE: Looks like the creatensis.pl is expecting a NSIS script called Master.

Why is makensis expecting looking for a script called Master?  The command looks like it it should be looking for the QGIS-Installer.nsi script.

I am using Windows 8.1 64 bit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did some manual editing of the command above and figured out why makensis was looking for "Master'".  My eyes are not what they used to be and that extra ' sneaked by me.

> -DDISPLAYED_NAME='QGIS 'Master ' (2.9.0)'

UPDATE: It's definitely a Windows thing.  The problem is with Windows interpretation of the single quote.  I found some good details [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6156952/perl-command-line-single-vs-double-quotes-for-directory-arguments).

Also, the NSIS script it is expecting is not in the same directory so I ended up getting this command to run:

> makensis -V1 -DVERSION_NAME="Wien" -DVERSION_NUMBER="2.8.2" -DBINARY_REVISION=1 -DVERSION_INT="2080201" -DQGIS_BASE="QGIS Wien" -DINSTALLER_NAME="QGIS-OSGeo4W-2.8.2-1-Setup-x86_64.exe" -DDISPLAYED_NAME="QGIS Wien (2.8.2)" -DSHORTNAME="qgis" -DINSTALLER_TYPE="OSGeo4W" -DPACKAGE_FOLDER="osgeo4w/unpacked-x86_64" -DLICENSE_FILE="osgeo4w/unpacked-x86_64/apps/qgis/doc/LICENSE" -DARCH="x86_64" ../QGIS-Installer.nsi